# Create a compiler error when a variable is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to trigger a custom compiler error when the developer forgot to enter a key in LocalizedStrings, in order to alert him this would cause the app will show the key instead the text. Personally I think that's perfect, but I have been required to launch a compiler error because the app has to many cases and to protect the developer in case of absentmindedness.

The method inside which is suppose to receive the key, would be something like:

```
- (NSString *) localizedString:(NSString *)key {
  HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO TRHROW THE COMPILER ERROR
}
```

Comment: If you have a certain nomenclature (like prefixing, using dot syntax, etc. for the keys), you could test if the key is equal to the value. If yes, throws an error.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a compile time error, look into annotating the argument with `_Nonnull`:

```
-(NSString *)localizedString:(NSString * _Nonnull)key
```

...and turning on the `-Wnullable-to-nonnull-conversion` warning with `-Werror` to turn this into an error. The main problem to deal with here is going to be the masses of existing code that will now fail because of nullable-to-nonnull conversions elsewhere, requiring a proliferation of annotations throughout your source code. This probably isn't going to be a workable solution but you can investigate it at least.

If you want a runtime error in debug mode only, use `NSAssert` or `NSParameterAssert`:

```
NSParameterAssert(key != nil);
// OR:
NSAssert(key != nil, "key must be non-nil");
// or just
NSAssert(key, "key must be non-nil");
```

If you always want a runtime error, throw an exception either with `@throw` or the convenience method:

```
if (!key) {
    [NSException raise:@"MyException" format:@"key must be non-nil"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all Mike, the problem i find is the setting "turning on the -Wnullable-to-nonnull-conversion" is not present in Xcode 8. I am finally developing a script for that use.

Comment: You need to add it to the "Other Warnings Flags" build setting

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way.

```
-(NSString *) localizedString:(NSString *)key
 {

  if (key == nil || key == (id)[NSNull null])
  {
        NSException* myException = [NSException
                                    exceptionWithName:@"NullException"
                                    reason:@"You have passed null value in key"
                                    userInfo:nil];

        @throw myException;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a compile time error, its a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here. 
 1. Compile time error
 2. Run time error

Your build will succeed as there is no problem with the syntax. Hence there can be no compile time error here.

What you actually need is a mechanism to fail the build when the app is about to be built.

This can be achieved by using build phases.
Go to build phases. Add your script which would look for keys in your code and check for the same key in your .string files. Essentially, you'll not initailize the building process when your script fails